# mysqldump big MyISAM table starts fast and suddenly slows down

Tags: performance, io, mysql

calling mysqldump for a database containing innodb & myisam tables.
Dump still runs very fast when it comes to a fat MyISAM table with 11GB size.
Fast means iotop shows me more than 70MB/s write performance. 
I view the process in mytop so i know it happens at a big table.
Dump files grows up to 8GB and then suddenly the I/O is only about 1 MB/s.

Server Load is OK, no other processes running.
Tried to change my.cnf settings but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Performance depends on a few factors.

I had to create [an alternative solution to Mysqldump](https://github.com/uniVocity/load-mysql-dump/) for a client to make them load a 42GB dump file (with more than 1 billion rows)

For reference: originally, MySQLDump took 3.9 days on a 16 core server with 64Gb ram and a 10 disk SSD array.

Using [uniVocity](http://www.univocity.com/pages/about-univocity) We loaded the same data in 90 minutes, using a 3 year old laptop. You can use it with a 30 day evaluation license to load this.

Other than that, here are a few things that may impact performance:

**Check if you have this on your dump file** to disable constraints:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'
```

If it doesn't add them or **alter the create table script to remove all constraints.** If you have constraints enabled (primary keys, foreign keys, etc) while running your dump load, the process will get slower over time as the database will validate these contraints on every insert against a growing number of possibilities (more PK's and FK's).

**If you are using InnoDB** (not exactly your case but it may help someone else), add this to your `my.cfg` file:

```
innodb_doublewrite = 0
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8000M
# innodb_log_file_size = 512M - If I enable this one the server won't start. Couldn't identify why.
log-bin = 0
innodb_support_xa = 0
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
```